# Show that if $T \in \mathcal{H}$ then $(T(z_1),T(z_2),T(z_3),T(z_4))=(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ be disctint points of $\hat{\Bbb{C}}$, and let
>
> $$(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=\frac{z_{1}-z_{2}}{z_{1}-z_{4}} \cdot \frac{z_{3}-z_{4}}{z_{3}-z_{2}}$$
>
> Be the *cross ratio* (I think that's how its called).
>
> Show that if $T \in \mathcal{H}$ then $(T(z_1),T(z_2),T(z_3),T(z_4))=(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ (where $\mathcal{H}$ is the group of homographies)

I tried by defining the homography given by the cross ratio

$$S(z)=\frac{z-z_{2}}{z-z_{4}} \cdot \frac{z_{3}-z_{4}}{z_{3}-z_{2}}$$

And consider $T$ as an arbitrary homography, $T(z)=\frac{a_1z + a_2}{a_3z+a_4}$ but it turns out to be painfully long. Is there any more elegant way to do it?

Comment: This is precisely theorem 12, in chapter 3 of the book "Complex Analysis" by L. Ahlfors (3rd edition). See the short proof there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

The trick is that you can write an homography as a composition of following simple homographies:

$$z \mapsto az$$
$$z \mapsto z+b$$
$$z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$$

And for each of those the result is simple to prove.